# Timestamps, majorating and sum

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, timestamp

I'm with a problem doing a part of a program, I hope you can help me.

I have this three columns in excel;

```
01-01-2012 00:15    A   7,160000

01-01-2012 00:30    A   1,600000

01-01-2012 00:45    C   3,040000

01-01-2012 01:00    A   1,560000

01-01-2012 01:15    A   0,000000

01-01-2012 01:30    D   0,000000

01-01-2012 01:45    A   0,000000
```

t goes until 31-01-2012 23:45

And now I want to read them into MATLAB and convert them into 3 new matrix with this format;

Timestamp

01-01-2012 00:00

01-01-2012 01:00

(...)

Period

A

A

Price

11,800000

10

So basically I want a program that read's timestamp and keep's day month year and hour (ignoring the minutes), for that period of time it needs to show the most repetitive value in periods of one hour (for example: it will give A to 00 and C to 01) and finally I want it to sum the prices for that hour (so it will sum the price at 00:15 + price at 00:30 etc.)

It will be a huge help, if you can solve me this problem.

P.S In the 1 hour periods I will always have one most repetitive marker (3 of A and 1 C, 3 D and 1 A etc.) I could find in this month 4 markers, A B C D. This markers aren't cyclic but I will find it all across the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like your main issue is reading the data from Excel and get it in a format you can work with. If so:

Check out [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). You have a lot of possibilities there. You can for instance use the following syntax:

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(___)
```

but if you are new to MATLAB and don't require the most efficient way, I would recommend you to read each of the columns separately. *Note:* This is not the best way, but it's the easiest way in my opinion. You can use this command on each of the columns (thus calling it three times):

```
num = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange)
```

Check out [this page](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/import_export/when-to-convert-dates-from-excel-files.html) to see how you can handle the dates. In summary, convert the dates to numeric values in Excel. Since you have hours and minutes, this will be a decimal number representing the number of days since Jan 01, 1900 (or Jan 02, 1904 if on MAC). Since MATLAB counts from Jan 01, 0000, you need to add some 1900 years after reading the file (check the reference I gave to see how).

One way to handle that you don't want minutes is to convert to [datevec](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html), and zero out the last columns (this way you will also remove the information):

```
[Y, M, D, H, MN, S] = datevec(___) ;
% or
date_vector = datevec(___); 
% Where you just don't use the MN and S variables
```

If you want the dates looking like dates, convert the datevec to [datestring](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html). Check out `formatOut`, and you can choose the format you want.

Try out the above. I'm afraid I can't do that work for you.

To get the most repetitive values, check out [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/mode.html). `mode(X)` returns the sample mode of `X`, which is the most frequently occurring value in X. You can also replicate this functionality by combining some of the following: [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) or [`all`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/all.html). And you can of course use `sum` to sum the values.

If it's only the last part here your stuck on, I suggest you rephrase the question a bit. If it's both, and you get stuck on the last part after doing the above, I suggest you ask it as a separate question, as that won't be related to reading it from Excel.

Good luck =)

Comment: Thx for answering, I will rephrase my question, in a new post, I have here three problems.